# Angularjs UI-Router state change changes functionality of Google-API directive

Tags: angularjs, google-api, angular-ui-router, state, directive

I am using a google places autocomplete directive: [vs-google-autocomplete](https://github.com/vskosp/vsGoogleAutocomplete)

which works fine. The problem is, if we change the $state (by back / forward button, or just ui-sref="testroute", or $state.go()), it suddenly does not work the way it worked before.

I set up a plnkr:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    console.log("place_changed");
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(element[0], 'keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 9)
        console.log("keydown");
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wbhEWds1pY1bWrguV40U?p=preview

You can enter an address and just hit enter. Then open the console. You will see:

1. keydown
2. place_changed

but if you now click on route2 and then back on route1, enter another address and press the enter button, console will log:

1. place_changed
2. keydown

The order of the eventhandlers changed. It seems that google search / - functionality is somehow broken, when google is loaded once, then the $state changes and you again try to use google.

Also, there is a second .pac container in the dom, and I guess google is somehow loaded twice or something while the controller just reloads.

Do you know why this behaviour happens and how I can prevent that or do you have at least an idea on how to workaround this problem? I need keydown to be before place_changed. The google search still works in the plnkr, but it is buggy a bit. I think it is a problem with angularjs/$state loading the controller / view and the directive or something.

//edit:

I guess it is not really a problem with the vs-google directive nor google itself, maybe just they way of them being initiated. Vs-google takes the element of the directive and initializes its code. Because google-API is included in the index.html file and a directive loads on state change, it seems that it reinitializes the DOM element or something, but still, the event is just called once